# grep freezes up

Tags: grep

I'm having trouble using grep, I have ubuntu 18.04 installed on Win 10. It freezes up for the simplest of commands, I can cancel it and it makes a new file if I want to, but it doesn't write anything in to it.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ ls
$ sudo grep "Werk!" > new
^C
$ ls
new
$ cat new
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What do you think what `grep` does? A usual `grep` command line has the form `grep SEARCH_TERM FILENAME` – and no need for `sudo`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You are grep'ing STDIN, so it hangs forever waiting for input which never comes.

You probably meant to include "." as an argument to grep, and -r (recursive), to grep the current directory.

```
grep -r hello .
```

Other people also find the default behavior of `grep` less than ideal so you'll find some `grep` alternatives don't have this problem. For example the [Silver Searcher](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) goes by the name `ag` and by default searches the current directory recursively, so your guess about the correct syntax would have been correct for `ag`:

```
ag hello
```

`ag` also defaults to a case-insensitive search unless you include an uppercase letter, which is also arguably what you want. It also defaults to using color and using the more powerful PCRE regex engine (like Perl) instead of the weaker, older glob-style matching that `grep` defaults to.

Usability problems with `grep` like this are why you should use a newer alternative when can and only use `grep` when you have to. `grep` is still useful to know a standard tool for shell scripts you may share and as a standard utility on any Linux box you will log into.

"ripgrep" and "ack" are other good alternative to grep.

Comment: I think `.` will only grep the (files in the) current directory if the `-r` (or `-R`) option is given as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yo've missed second argument of `grep` command that specify file in which you are searching the pattern.

Please follow [man 1 grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to get help about `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want record texts in file "new", That can done by using "echo texts > new".